# Backbone - Overriding app links

Tags: backbone.js

I am using the following code to divert all clicked links to the Backbone router instead of hitting the server:

```
$(document).delegate("a:not([data-bypass])", "click", function(evt) {
                var href = $(this).attr("href");
                var protocol = this.protocol + "//";

                if (href && href.slice(0, protocol.length) !== protocol &&
                href.indexOf("javascript:") !== 0) {
                    evt.preventDefault();

                    Backbone.history.navigate(href, true);
                }
            });
```

It works well enough but it is causing issues when trying to use "preventDefault", for example:

```
onCancel: function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   this.hide();
}
```

The preventDefault function here is being ignored and Backbone is following the link. I managed to fix this by adding the following line of code to the top function:

```
if(evt.isDefaultPrevented())
   return false;
```

But I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: I wonder, why should you delegate it? Haven't you used `Backbone.Routes`?

Comment: I have a generic ajax load function for basic template views, otherwise I defer to the router.

Comment: why don't you reset all your `hrefs` after it got rendered instead of doing that `delegate` work? If i don't get you correctly, can you show me some example what you are doing inside that delegate before calling `Backbone.history.navigate`